# validation using javascript in php

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I want to validate my contact form using JavaScript but I dont know the validation codes and where to include,

I want validations should occur before redirecting to thank_you.php page

Plz help me...

**HTML**

```
<fieldset>
  <?php include("formcode.php"); ?>
</fieldset>
```

**formcode.php**

```
<form method='post' action="database.php">
  NAME: <input type='text' name='name' id='name' />
  Email: <input type='text' name='email' id='email' />
  Contact: <input type='text' name='contact' id='contact' />
  Tour:
   <select  id="tour" name="tour" >
        <option value="">--Select Tours--</option>
        <option value="Tour1">Tour1</option>
        <option value="Tour2">Tour2</option>

    </select><br/>
  Location:
    <select  id="location" name="location" >
        <option value="">--Select Your Location--</option>
        <option value="Loc1">Loc1</option>
        <option value="Loc2">Loc2</option>
    </select><br/>   
  Comment:<br />
  <textarea name='comment' id='comment' /></textarea><br />

  <input type='submit' value='Submit' />  

</form>
```

**database.php**

```
<?php
if( $_POST )
{
  $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");

  if (!$con)
  {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

  mysql_select_db("db_name", $con);

  $users_name = $_POST['name'];
  $users_email = $_POST['email'];
  $users_contact = $_POST['contact'];
  $users_tour = $_POST['tour'];
  $users_location = $_POST['location'];
  $users_comment = $_POST['comment'];

  $users_name = mysql_real_escape_string($users_name);
  $users_email = mysql_real_escape_string($users_email);
  $users_contact = mysql_real_escape_string($users_contact);
  $users_tour = mysql_real_escape_string($users_tour);
  $users_location = mysql_real_escape_string($users_location);
  $users_comment = mysql_real_escape_string($users_comment);

  $query = "
  INSERT INTO `db_name`.`dbtable` (`id`, `name`, `email`, `contact`, `tour`, `location`, `comment`, `timestamp`, `articleid`)
  VALUES ( Null, '$users_name', '$users_email', '$users_contact', '$users_tour', '$users_location', '$users_comment', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);";

  mysql_query($query);

  $url = 'thank_you.php';
  echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV=Refresh CONTENT="0; URL='.$url.'">';

  mysql_close($con);

  include("mail.php"); 
}
?>
```

Comment: Try to wrtie some validation code so we can help you if you can't make it work

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_form_validation.asp

Comment: You have to validate your form in PHP too, and not rely only on JS validation.

Comment: If you want to validate with _JavaScript_, or will be even before the data is sent to `database.php`.

Comment: but starters can start from there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perform the validation using javascript before submitting the form as shown below. First give id to your form so you can easily submit via JS

```
<form method='post' action="database.php" id='frm'></form>
make a call to validate function from the submit button like this

<input type='submit' value='Button' onclick=javacript:validate(); />


 <script language=javascript> //easy one by one validation. this allow full control
     function validate(){
        if (document.getElementById('name').value==''){
            alert('name is required');//customize this for your need. You may use div display
             return;
         }                         
          //repeat the above for each form tags and values

         document.getElementById('frm').submit();//submit the form
    }

 </script>
```

There are more advanced [JQuery plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) for validation, the above is the simple primitive method

Comment: thanks, i have done accordingly you guided, validations are working....